# Add multiple values to single key in python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am going to read text file using python and trying to create dictionary which contains unique key and multiple values to it.

Code:

```
f = open("address.txt", 'r')
email = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = line.strip().split()
    if k.strip() in email:
       email[k.strip()].append(v.strip())
    else:
       email[k.strip()] = [v.strip()]

print email
f.close()
```

Input:

```
user1@abc.com  192.168.56.3 hostname5
user2@xyz.com  192.168.56.4 hostname2
user1@abc.com  192.168.56.5 hostname3
user2@xyz.com  192.168.56.7 hostname1
user1@abc.com  192.168.56.6 hostname4
user1@abc.com  192.168.56.9 hostname3
```

Expected Output:

```
user1@abc.com 192.168.56.3 hostname5 192.168.56.5 hostname3 192.168.56.6 hostname4 192.168.56.9 hostname3 
user2@xyz.com  192.168.56.4 hostname2 192.168.56.7 hostname1
```

I am getting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "final.py", line 4, in <module>
 k, v = line.strip().split()
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I don't know what's wrong with the code? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Isn't the problem that you're trying to store 3 values (email, IP, hostname) in two variables (k, v)? Start by storing the result into three variables, e.g. k, v, a = ...

Answer (score 1):

Just to make your life easier, you could either use `dict.setdefault` or `collections.defaultdict`:

```
import collections

email = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open("address.txt", 'r') as f: 

    for line in f:
        k, *v = line.strip().split() # use catch all unpacking here    
        email[k].append(tuple(v))
```

`email` is a dictionary of `key : list of values` pairs. This is what it looks like:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'user1@abc.com': [('192.168.56.3', 'hostname5'),
              ('192.168.56.5', 'hostname3'),
              ('192.168.56.6', 'hostname4'),
              ('192.168.56.9', 'hostname3')],
             'user2@xyz.com': [('192.168.56.4', 'hostname2'),
              ('192.168.56.7', 'hostname1')]})
```

---

If you want to go the further step and get your data in the exact form specified in your question (although there is little you can do with data in this form), here's how you do it ([thanks Alexander!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604504/add-multiple-values-to-single-key-in-python-dictionary/45604598?noredirect=1#comment78168761_45604598)):

```
In [486]: {k: [" ".join([" ".join(tup) for tup in email[k]])] for k in email}
Out[486]: 
{'user1@abc.com': ['192.168.56.3 hostname5 192.168.56.5 hostname3 192.168.56.6 hostname4 192.168.56.9 hostname3'],
 'user2@xyz.com': ['192.168.56.4 hostname2 192.168.56.7 hostname1']}
```

Comment: @Alexander This is to go inside the for loop?

Comment: @Alexander `line.split()` will handle variable spaces: example: `In [482]: 'foo     bar baz'.split();
Out[482]: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']` so another level of stripping is not required.

Comment: I was worried about other whitespace such as `\t`.  Not an issue with `split`, however:  "If sep is not specified or is None, any
whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
from the result."

Comment: To get the format closer to the desired form, perhaps:  `{k: " ".join([" ".join(tup) for tup in email[k]]) for k in email}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the three values read from each line into three variables, not two. Try:

```
f = open("address.txt", 'r')
email = {}
for line in f:
    k, v, a = line.strip().split()
    if k.strip() in email:
        email[k.strip()].append(v.strip())
        email[k.strip()].append(a.strip())


    else:
        email[k.strip()] = [v.strip(), a.strip()]

print email
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

`line.split()` returns a list with 3 elements which you are trying to store in 2, you can avoid that by splitting the line first then slice it to get two variables. You also don't need to use `strip()` when you use `split()`. For example:

```
with open("address.txt", 'r') as f:
    email = {}
        for line in f:
    line = line.split()
    k, v = line[0], line[1:]
    email[k] = email.get(k, []) + v  
    # instead of using if/else, email.get(k, []) returns the value if available or an empty list if not

for k, v in email.iteritems():
    print('{} {}'.format(k, ' '.join(v)))
```

output:

```
user2@xyz.com 192.168.56.4 hostname2 192.168.56.7 hostname1
user1@abc.com 192.168.56.3 hostname5 192.168.56.5 hostname3 192.168.56.6 hostname4 192.168.56.9 hostname3
```